# Google Spreadsheets ImportXML and XPath

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I'm trying to extract rate data from below URL by using Google Spreadsheets:

used importXML() function with following XPath sting:

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.superrichthailand.com/#!/en/exchange","//span[@class=""ng-binding""]")`

Which, it should return every entry in the pages all the rate but return empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping data to google sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Sheets IMPORTXML can't access dynamically generated data, only the source code in the file referred by the URL.