# IMPORTXML- Could not fetch URL - specific domain

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to check a particular parameter on a page using importxml but I keep getting "Could not fetch url". I'm trying to check if the casino is Closed or restricted.

Heres what I'm using.

```
=importxml("https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/reviews/winning-casino","/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div/span")
```

And

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/reviews/chipstars-casino","//*[@id='casino-review__new']/div[1]/div/span")
```

This used to work in the past (about 2 years back), doesn't seem to work now.

I'm not sure how to get this to work.

Comment: Have you verified that the content in the page that you want to fetch is not showing the information through JavaScript? If the content that you want to fetch is JavaScript generated then `IMPORTXML` and `IMPORTHTML` will not return any information.

Comment: I've tried disabling javascript on the page, and the page loads with the necessary data. I may be wrong, but it appears like the content is not js dependant.

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript/74245749#74245749