# Extract all <li> with the class="myTag" but without <small>

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I am struggling with the `ImportXML` function from Google Spreadsheet. A specific webpage has this content:

```html
<li class="myTag">
    <a href="/xyz/abc/">
        Jouets
        <small class="hidden">
            <span>235&nbsp;6453&nbsp;sous-section</span>
            <span>1231&nbsp;765&nbsp;produits</span>
            <span>12155&nbsp;654&nbsp;images</span>
        </small>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="myTag">
    <a href="/xyz/def/">
        Livres
        <small class="hidden">
            <span>235&nbsp;6453&nbsp;sous-section</span>
            <span>1231&nbsp;765&nbsp;produits</span>
            <span>12155&nbsp;654&nbsp;images</span>
        </small>
    </a>
</li>
```

I want to extract all `li` tags with the `class="myTag"` but without the `<small>` section, in order to have this list:

- Jouets
- Livres

I have written this XPath expression:

```
=IMPORTXML(B1; '//li[@class='myTag'].ReplaceAll("<[^>]*>", "", "")')
```

But I have the `#N/A` error.

How can I extract just the first elements (Jouets, Livres) without the <small> section?

---

**Originality of this question**

[Scraping data to Google Sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript) is about dynamic web pages which is not my case. My page is already generated in HTML content - I can already extract the full content within the `<li>` tag with the parameter `'//li[@class='myTag']'`.

My point is to *exclude* the `<small>` content which is glued.
I am looking to get this list:

- Jouets
- Livres

and not this one:

- Jouets235 6453 sous-section1231 765 produits12155 654 images
- Livres235 6453 sous-section1231 765 produits12155 654 images

Comment: Can you provide the URL for testing it?

Comment: Yes: https://www.universalis.fr/classification/

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the URL.  When I saw the HTMl of your URL, I cannot find the values of `Jouets` and `Livres`. And also, I cannot find the "li" tag with the class of `myTag`. I apologize for this.

Comment: Sorry, I anonymised the content.
Here is the full importxml function:
=IMPORTXML(https://www.universalis.fr/classification/; '//li[@class='with-counter']')

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I anonymised the content. `, I couldn't notice it. I apologize for this.

Comment: Did you succeed with the test?
`=IMPORTXML('https://www.universalis.fr/classification/'; '//li[@class='with-counter']')`

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand your expected values. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. When you use your provided formula of `=IMPORTXML('https://www.universalis.fr/classification/'; '//li[@class='with-counter']')`, what did you obtain the values and what values do you want to retrieve? So, can I ask you about the detail of your expected value?

Comment: Thank you.  
Currently, with this formula I have this result (just pasting the first lines):

- `Arts1 069 sous-thèmes15 778 articles11 949 médias` ; 
- `Astronomie et astrophysique107 sous-thèmes570 articles696 médias` ; 
- `Chimie147 sous-thèmes1 042 articles1 087 médias`

But I am attempting to get only:

- `Arts` ; 
- `Astronomie et astrophysique` ; 
- `Chimie`

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected values, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following reply,

> Currently, with this formula I have this result (just pasting the first lines): - `Arts1 069 sous-thèmes15 778 articles11 949 médias` ; - `Astronomie et astrophysique107 sous-thèmes570 articles696 médias` ; - `Chimie147 sous-thèmes1 042 articles1 087 médias` But I am attempting to get only: - `Arts` ; - `Astronomie et astrophysique` ; - `Chimie`

How about the following XPath?

#### Modified XPath:

```
//li[@class='with-counter']/a/text()
```

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.universalis.fr/classification/"; "//li[@class='with-counter']/a/text()")
```

#### Testing:

[image]

Comment: @macaaron Thank you for replying and testing it. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.