# How can I scrape data from a specific URL using Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from link below : https://c.8891.com.tw/bmw/3-series-coupe/Summary.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCOpr.png)

I tried:

```
=importhtml("https://c.8891.com.tw/bmw/3-series-coupe/Summary.html","table",0)
```

and

```
=importxml("https://c.8891.com.tw/bmw/3-series-coupe/Summary.html","//*[@id='gbox_grid']")
```

and I also want other year information and this url
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcart.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy5Ag.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping data to Google Sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Data on the page gets loaded via javascript, for the page you're scraping it gets loaded from this [url](https://c.8891.com.tw/summary/models?nk=779). So you'll either need to use something like
[puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) that opens the page in chromium to scrape the things you want
or if you really want to use google sheets you could use the [url](https://c.8891.com.tw/summary/models?nk=779) I wrote to load JSON into it following these [steps](https://apipheny.io/import-json-google-sheets/) but that will be only for this page.

Comment: Thanks !
But this gives me some ideas to improve search speed.