# how to get dividend data from yahoo finance to google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, yahoo-finance

I try to get dividend data from yahoo finance to google sheets
In my understanding it should use importxml

I copy url and xpath from browser for this function

this is my code
=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch","/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]")

i also try to import non us stock with no success in this code
=IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AALI.JK?p=AALI.JK&.tsrc=fin-srch","/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]")

but it return #n/a with message resouce at url not found
where did it went wrong?
or if yahoo finance banned scrapping data please give some suggestion web with dividen data available for indonesian and us stocks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping data to Google Sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript)