# Why doesn't the UrlfetchApp.fetch command get the complete html?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping

hello i've been doing a project to analyse a chess tournament.
Therefore i want to scrape the data from the website https://turniere.schachklub-kelheim.de/BAD-2022-U16/einzel. However it did't work as i planned.

I used this following code in Google apps script, but it doesn't give me the complete html.

```
function getLichessLink() {
  var url="https://turniere.schachklub-kelheim.de/BAD-2022-U16/einzel";
  var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var pattern = new RegExp('<div id="root">(.*?)</div>', "g");
  var match = response.match(pattern)
}
```

my logger shows that the response is missing several tag and  is empty, altough there should be content in there.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: When your URL is retrieved using `UrlFetchApp.fetch`, it seems that `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.` is included in the HTML. Unfortunately, in the current stage, `UrlFetchApp.fetch` cannot retrieve the HTML by executing Javascript. I thought that this might be an answer to `Why doesn't the UrlfetchApp.fetch command get the complete html?`. If this was not your expected answer, I apologize.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping data to Google Sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript)