# How to get the URL via ImportXML of the first ten Google Search results?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, xpath-2.0

I am trying to get 10 links via a google sheet from page 1 of the Google Search Results (not including any links to advertised links):

I am using the following formula, but It's ERROR

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=hello+world&start=00";//div/cite)
```

please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping data to Google Sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript)

Comment: `but It's ERROR` The reason that it is error is because the data for the URL is created dynamically by JavaScript. You can't use IMPORTXML (or IMPORTHTML) to get data from that site.

Comment: @Tedinoz So, Do you have any solution for me?

Comment: ‘So, Do you have any solution for me?’ No. Did you read that other question? Your question is a duplicate; it will soon be closed. If there is an answer to your question, then it is covered in that other question.