# IMPORTHTML function in Google Sheets not working

Tags: google-sheets, import

I am trying to import a data table from a financial website (https://www.macrotrends.net/)

I use the following code in a cell:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AAPL/apple/income-statement", "table", 1)
```

It results in

> Error
> Imported content is empty.

I suspect the way the website was built the table is not technically a table according to Google Sheets or something along those lines, but I don't have the experience in HTML to know. Any fixes?

Comment: Can you provide your expected value from the URL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping data to Google Sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript)