# How to get the "innerHTML" of a Html element in a downloaded web page?

Tags: google-apps-script, html-parsing, urlfetch

I'm trying to create a Google Apps Script function that returns the inner HTML of an ID element of a webpage.

Using the JavaScript console of the web browser, this would do it:

```
document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML
```

In Google Apps Script:

```
function getValue(symbol) {
  
  symbol= 'ABCD';

  const url = `https://example.com/${symbol}`;

  const options = {
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/xml'},
    method: 'GET'
  };

  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  const contentText = res.getContentText();
 
  // ????
}
```

From the code above, I've managed to extract the whole web page content - but how do I get the inner html of the `myID` id?

Comment: You can't really initiate any communication to rendered html from apps script. You can use set interval and google.script.run to send that information from html to appscript

Comment: You're looking for Cheerio. There's a GAS  version.

Answer (score 1):

Server side JavaScript is different from client side JavaScript(Browser).  There's no API for `window` or `document` or any of it's methods server side. To parse html, you may use server side html parsers like [Cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/). There's a GAS fork by @tani/@3846masa [here](https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs), which may work for you. There are also differences between how the server renders the html/js vs what is available in the downloaded html. See [Scraping data to Google Sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74237688/)

If you're looking for xml parser, there's a [inbuilt one](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/).

Comment: I guess Cheerio is what I need here, I'll have a look. Have no idea why they closed the question, downgraded??? Anyway, thanks for helping!