# What is the XML query to put this weather data into a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

I am trying to put weather data from this website into a google sheet and I have been unable to find an XPATH query that will work.  Can you help me?

https://tsvweather.brownrice.com/dailysnow.php

I have tried to copy the XPath from Chrome, but when I tried the following syntax in google sheets the result is Error, Imported Content is Empty.

`=importxml("https://tsvweather.brownrice.com/dailysnow.php","/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/table/tbody")`

Comment: Doubt that page is actually xml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping data to Google Sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript)